# difference between these 2 things

Tags: python

What is the difference between

```
theList + [4]
```

and

```
theList.append(4)
```

They both add the item at index 4 to 'theList'? But, my instructor said there is a specific difference between the 2?

Comment: Why are you asking here? Why didn't you *ask your instructor*?! Also that is about the worst title ever.

Answer (score 2):

The first piece of code **creates a new list** that has all of the items in `theList` and `4`:

```
>>> theList = [1, 2, 3]
>>> theList + [4]  # This creates a new list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> theList  # theList is unchanged
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

The second piece **mutates** `theList` by adding `4` to the end of it:

```
>>> theList = [1, 2, 3]
>>> theList.append(4)  # This does not create a new list
>>> theList  # theList is changed
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having this code:

```
L = [1]
print id(L) # 36529288
L = L + [4]
print id(L) # 36579976
```

You can see that both `id`s are different, because this way of appending an element, **creates a new list**.

While in this:

```
L = [1]
print id(L) # 37119112
L.append(4)
print id(L) # 37119112
```

the list is **modified in-place** (doesn't create a new one).

Answer (score 0):

This one concatenates two lists. Note that `theList` is not modified.

```
theList + [4]
```

This one appends `4` to the `theList`

```
theList.append(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

One is an expression, the other is a statement. The first evaluates to a new list which has the contents of theList with 4 at the end. If you referred to theList later on it would not contain 4.

Conversely, the second actually mutates theList and gives it a new value, which was its old value with the 4 added.

Answer (score -1):

There is a space difference between the two. It would be better to do theList.append(4) if possible because it avoids the overhead of creating a new list:

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.getsizeof([4]) 
80
>>>sys.getsizeof(4)
24
```